# Removing duplicates from SQL results and showing other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get information from my database but removing duplicate values while maintaining other column data. I have tried using distinct as it was the only real thing i could find information on. I tried the below and this works to remove the duplicate names so i have "Name Name2 Name3" removing the duplicate name2:

SELECT DISTINCT `Column 1` FROM `table` WHERE `column3` LIKE 'Item1'

I am now stuck with trying to get it to display column 3 and column 2 data the below is what the table currently looks like:

```
 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
 | Name     | 71       | Item1    |
 | Name2    | 78       | Item1    |
 | Name2    | 77       | Item1    |
 | Name3    | 75       | Item1    |
 | Name     | 75       | Item2    |
```

And the below is what i am trying to get as a result:

```
 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
 | Name     | 71       | Item1    |
 | Name2    | 77       | Item1    |
 | Name3    | 75       | Item1    |
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be amazing!

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic for choosing one of the two `Name2` records?  You never explicitly mentioned this in your question.

Comment: What entry of column2 and column3 you want to pick corresponding to unique entry of column1

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a choice to the data displayed in column 2; if you want a random choice you can do something like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3  FROM table WHERE column3 LIKE 'Item1' GROUP BY Column1
```

EDIT : If you want a random value on Column2 with an aggregated function you can do:

```
SELECT Column1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Column2 order by rand()), ',', 1) AS Column2,
       Column3
FROM table
WHERE column3 LIKE 'Item1'
GROUP BY Column1
```

Comment: It is sad that an answer containing a poorly formed query would get an upvote.  This is an aggregation query where the `SELECT` column contains unaggregated columns that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This violated SQL syntax rules.  As for MySQL, it quite supporting this (by default) several versions ago.

Comment: it's why i have said "You have to make a choice..." i will edit my answer as soon as he replys and say what he wants for the column2 your answer is false if he doesn't want the min...

Answer (score 0):

From the desired output, I think, that following query will do the job

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3  
FROM t
WHERE c3 LIKE 'i1'
  and c2 in (select min(c2) from t group by c1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e79eef/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select t.column1, min(t.column2) as column2, min(t.column3) as column3
from t
where column3 = 'Item1'
group by t.column1;
```

This returns one row for each value in `column1`, with the minimum value of `column2` where `column3` is `'Item1'`.